# Replacing text to class function

Tags: php

I'm came with one problem and thinking is there any solution of my programming way. I hope everyone will understand problem and might help.

I have html template let's say like that:

```
<title>{Content~title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {Content~Display("testas")}
</body>
```

And I have a class called Content:

```
class Content {

    public $title = "Test";

    public function __construct(){}

    public function Display($text){
        return $text;
    }       
}
```

Now, I have script which load class and puts in array like that:

```
$this->objects[$class] = new $class(); // in this case: Content class
```

After that I'm trying to replace my tags {Content~title} and {Content~Display("testas")} via this code:

```
$replaceContent = $this->objects[$class_name];
$content = str_replace($current,$replaceContent->{$key},$content); // key- Display("testas")
```

With title (because it's class property) works good, but with function I came with error:

```
Notice:  Undefined property: Content::$Display("testas") ..
```

However if I'm trying to use like:

```
echo $replaceContent->Display("TEST");
```

Work's fine... any ideas how to replace my tag to function content from class?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a non-existing field of the class [as the error states].

As you have a function, you have to invoke it:

```
$replaceContent->{$key}( $content )
```

This will call your `Display()` function, which should be named in lower case by the way, and should do something more than just retuning its parameter I guess.

Comment: Hum.. It worked, but problem.. I can't use args etc:
Display("123456").. displays: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Content::Display("123456")()...

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the whole part into `key` variable. You should have 2 variables for example:

```
$functionName = 'Display';
$functionArg = 'testas';
```

and than:

```
$replaceContent->$functionName($functionArg)
```

Comment: Humm.. Thank you guys.. Your both solutions are the answers to my problem so I don't know for who I should click solved.. sorry :/